# How to store currency in mongodb, which data type to use?

Tags: php, mongodb, php-mongodb

**N.B.** There are multiple Questions on money and currency for mongodb but none of them resolved my problem or were not clear for me.

I'm using mongodb with PHP. and storing prices for a product. A product has different rate in different city.

This is how I'm storing value in string, my problem is in which data type do I store currency value in mongo so that I can sort and find according to city or price.

```
"price" : [
    {
        "city" : "mumbai",
        "price" : "6342"
    },
    {
        "city" : "banglore",
        "price" : "6323.50"
    },
    {
        "city" : "delhi",
        "price" : "5234"
    }
],
```

Comment: Looks like the example you've got there is pretty solid? Why can't you use that?

Comment: This is how I'm storing value, but it is string right now. I'm confused about int, float and string.

Comment: I'm dealing both of prices and currency in my job, and we are using double. Couldn't understand thay why you are using String ?

Comment: @quartaela I'm making schema right now, and i'm confused what to use. if you can give proper example and benefit will Upvote your answer.

Comment: I would use int which is then divided down into double, binary double can loose precision, especially in JS if you plan to do Map Reduces

Comment: The lack of a decimal or currency type is a known deficiency of MongoDb. https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-1393